# How to implement a status bar like the remote desktop connection bar?

Tags: .net, winforms

[image: RemoteDesktopStatusBar]

Does anyone know how to implement a WinForms control that behaves like the status bar in Remote Desktop?

It needs to float over the top and disappear when you move the cursor away (unless pinned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two examples that can help you to achieve this

[This is an example in how to customize certain aspects of the title bar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42223/Easy-Customize-Title-Bar)

[This video showing how to do a TitleBar from zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRFoPdC43cE)

The second one seems to be closer to what you need. Too bad there are not written instructions nor sound on the video